# How to use async method in MVC filter?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Actually I have created one filter in MVC by inheriting AuthorizationFilterAttribute.
Override OnAuthorization() method into the class.
In this OnAuthorization() method I tried to make async call of another method.
So my page was coming unresponsive.
Then I switched to sync call instead of async.
But I was thinking async would be good for me.

I tried by It page coming unresponsive. So cannot we use async in Filter or what is the issue

Comment: Could you please share the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ASP.NET Core try this:

```
public class CustomAuthorizationFilter : IAsyncAuthorizationFilter
{
     public async Task OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext filterContext)
     {
        // Do necessary staffs here
     }
}
```